# Laravel php artisan migrate Have Error 150

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, migration, migrate

i want to create category for company but i have this error :
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `sanat`.`#sql-53e_e7d` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `company_category` add constraint `company_category_company_id_foreign` foreign key (`company_id`) references `companies` (`id`) on delete cascade)

this is my migration code for category:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('type');
        $table->string('imageUrl')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('article_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('article_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['article_id', 'category_id']);
    });
    Schema::create('company_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['company_id', 'category_id']);
    });

}
```

so company table and categories table dont create.
when i remove this:

```
Schema::create('company_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->primary(['company_id', 'category_id']);
});
```

php artisan migrate worked .
where is the problem

this is my company migration:

```
Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->boolean('active')->default(false);
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('slug');
    $table->text('aboutUs');
    $table->integer('tell');
    $table->string('address');
    $table->string('tag');
    $table->string('logoUrl');
    $table->string('slideUrl')->unique();
    $table->string('facebookUrl');
    $table->string('instagramUrl');
    $table->string('telegramUrl');
    $table->string('whatsAppUrl');
    $table->string('websiteUrl');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: try delete this `$table->primary(['company_id', 'category_id']);`

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos No its not work

Comment: error display when create table company_category and categorie???

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos when i removed company_categories every things will be fine, when i replace it again and get php artisan migrate:status
| N    | 2018_08_28_110858_create_categories_table
| N    | 2018_09_02_104747_create_companies_table   
this 2 table dont migrate

Comment: Make sure that you create the companies table before you make the category_company table (same as Tim says)

Comment: Is your `companies` migration running before you attempt to set the foreign key on `company_category`? They run in order of file name (which is a timestamp)

Comment: first need run companies next categories after run others

Comment: @TimLewis How can i Create company Table before this
because i add php artisan migrate:refresh and its create When i add company_category its Drop

Comment: The order of your files in `database/migrations` folder is the order in which they are migrated (ascending for `migrate`, descending for `migrate:refresh`).

Comment: @TimLewisThank you very much, its worked